# Module import ignoring main field in package.json

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file that imports a module (in this case [react-intercom](https://github.com/nhagen/react-intercom)), in this module there is a package.json file with a main field pointing to `lib/index.js`

however, when importing using

`import { IntercomAPI } from 'react-intercom'`

typescript will ignore the main field and look for `react-intercom/index` instead

the application in this case is an angular app with embedded react instances

here is our tsconfig file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "#/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./src/typings.d.ts"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules", "build", "dist"],
  "include": ["./src/*.ts", "./src/**/*.ts"],
  "files": ["node_modules/ngx-i18next/index.ts"]
}
```

and our tsconfig.app file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/<appname>",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["app/*"],
      "#/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "typeRoots": ["./typings.d.ts", "node_modules/@types"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules",
    "../build",
    "../dist"
  ],
  "include": ["./*.ts", "./**/*.ts"],
  "files": ["../node_modules/ngx-i18next/index.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finaly figured out where the issues lied, and it was with the module and not our config

Turns out that [one of the last commit added an index.d.ts file at the base of the module](https://github.com/nhagen/react-intercom/commit/cf653b9eb4c2cf2133feb842ea1935f10ec7fa4b), and it looks like typescript checks for an index file in the given path before looking at the `main` entry in package.json

so it went from looking for react-intercom/lib/index.js to react-intercom/index.d.ts, which is a file [missing the typings for IntercomAPI](https://github.com/nhagen/react-intercom/pull/57)

Comment: Odd decision on TypeScript's part. You saved me time, thank you so much for following up on this!